# What is the difference between "was standing" vs "stood"? (Especially in the context of writing a formal report about past data)

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

Which one is correct and what is the difference between them?

> 1 The amount of sales was standing at $10000 in 1990.

> 2 The amount of sales stood at $10000 in 1990.

---

For example, consider this question in this context:

Suppose that the data that we have is that the amount of sales in 1989 was $5000, in 1990 was $10000, and in 1991 was $15000. Now suppose that we want to write a formal report about this data. Are both example sentences in my question legitimate and correct in this context?

Comment: I CV'd for lack of research, but this is also a duplicate of quite a few questions on ELL.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I added a specific context, so I think it is not a duplicate (or just about simple past vs past continuous) anymore .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those sentences there is no significant difference, just a matter of style. Both are grammatically valid, although I think (2) is more common. However, in other uses, there can be a difference.

> (3) He was standing on the corner.

> (4) He stood on the corner.

In (3) at the moment of interest "he" was in the process of standing on the corner.

In (4) he stood on the corner at some unspecified time in the past (or with the proper context in the present). And of course there are other senses of "standing" and "stood" that are not even close to interchangeable, such as:

> (5) One must have standing to bring a lawsuit.

> (6) She stood to gain a lot if the deal went through.

Comment: Suppose that the only data that we have is that the amount of sales in 1989 was $5000, in 1990 was $10000, in 1991 was $15000. Now suppose that we want to write a report about this data. Are both example sentences in my question legitimate and correct in this context?

Comment: @alireza Yes they are. English tenses do not give that level of specific information. The words must do that.

Answer (score 1):

**Progressive Past Tense**

The [progressive past tense](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-continuous-tense/) (also known as the Past Continuous Tense):

> The past continuous tense, also known as the past progressive tense, refers to a continuing action or state that was happening at some point in the past. The past continuous tense is formed by combining the past tense of to be (i.e., was/were) with the verb’s present participle (-ing word).

"Was standing" identifies an action that took place in the past that, from the perspective of the past, was still happening. "He was standing there when I left," meaning that the person continued to stand in the past forward to the present to the knowledge of the speaker.

**Simple Past Tense**

The [simple past tense](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/simple-past/):

> The simple past is a verb tense that is used to talk about things that happened or existed before now.

"Stood" identifies an action that happened in the past *that was completed in the past.* There is no expectation that the action continued beyond that moment of the past. "He stood there, then he left," is an example of an action in the past that was completed in the past.

**Summary of the differences**

The progressive past tense is used when you know the action continued beyond the time in the past you're talking about.

> She was flying to Venice for a vacation when her brother won the lottery. (The act of flying continues beyond the act of winning the lottery).

The simple past tense is used when you know the action was completed in the past.

> She flew to Venice for a vacation and didn't know her brother won the lottery. (The act of flying was completed without knowing about winning the lottery.)

**And concerning your examples**

> The amount of sales was standing at $10000 in 1990.

The above sentence (progressive past tense) means the amount of sales in 1990 was $10,000 *and continued to be $10,000 into the future beyond 1990* until something acts to modify the condition (the state of being $10,000).

> The amount of sales stood at $10000 in 1990.

The above sentence (simple past tense) means the amount of sales in 1990 was $10,000 *but it may not have stayed at $10,000.* The value may have changed later.

Comment: While this answer is generally correct on the uses of the past progressive, in the specific case of "was standing at" I think the implication that the price continued to be at the specified figure **after** the specified moment is really not valid. "The value was standing at X at time Y" simply means that the value was X at Y with no implication that it continued past Y. "Stand at" could be considered a separate phrasal verb.

Comment: Echoing what David said, with "*the person continued to stand in the past forward to the present to the knowledge of the speaker*" being another example that's not true. There's absolutely no claim about the present, only about what was happening in the past. It may be trivially true that the speaker doesn't know if it's still true or not, but the grammar doesn't carry that meaning, so it's not helpful to mention it.